# setError(R.string.bla) doesnt work?

Tags: android, string, resources, android-edittext

Is there a way of using resources for setError for Edittext?

I tried  setError.(getString(R.string.bla)) as well and context.getString(R.string.bla)

No of them sets the error the text bla corresponds in the strings.xml. it gets a number which I guess resources reference value.

Any Idea that how can I use the string resources for setError?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29) *(returns a CharSequence)* instead of `getString()` *(which returns a String)*. Example:

```
editText.setError(getText(R.string.bla));
```

Comment: Strangely enough but now it works:)  I just cleaned the project and setError.(getString(R.string.bla)) works now. cheers.